# Let's Encrypt challenge fails on Windows with Bitnami

Tags: windows, apache2, cloud, bitnami, lets-encrypt

I am trying to get an SSL certificate signed for a windows server in the cloud where I installed Bitnami which includes an apache2. I followed [this explanation](https://commaster.net/content/how-setup-lets-encrypt-apache-windows) using let's encrypt win simple.

I run the command:

```
letsencrypt.exe --manualhost vmurl.ofwebsever.net --webroot "C:\my\pathto\bitnami\apache\htdocs" --test
```

The "letsencrypt-win-simple" tool tells me the local path to the acme-challenge file and claims that it is not accessible via internet. It recommends me to whether the file is accessible via browser. However, I can actually access the file via my browser. I copied the exact link from the console output and I get to see the key in my browser (not in the cloud anymore!). Obviously, the key file is actually also put into my Apache htdocs folder. So how can narrow this down?

- Is bitnami/apache2 not suitable for Let's Encrypt win simple?
- Has Let's Encrypt win simple a bug here?
- Is it the cloud server?

Any help is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have any sort of security groups that could be blocking the access to the server?

Comment: I tried opening port 80 in the windows firewall. That was necessary to access the file via the browser. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Is the server running in a cloud provider like aws or is it a custom server?

Comment: Cloud provider. A smaller company.

Comment: Could you confirm if the Cloud provider sets firewall rules apart from the ones you set in the machine (for example, just like AWS security groups)

Comment: I am gonna talk them about it. They actually recommended me to use Let's Encrypt. Would that case allow me to access the file via different browsers (e.g. my Android phone) but potentially block the letsencrypt-win-simple tool?

Comment: If you can access externally then Let's Encrypt should be able as well (unless you are in some sort of VPN). I advise you to contact Let's Encrypt developers so they may give you a better hint about the issue. https://community.letsencrypt.org/

Comment: It worked after I got an official domain from the provider. It seems that it is not possible to get a certificate for the url of the vm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after I got an *official domain* from the provider. It seems that it is not possible to get a certificate for the url of the vm. The error message to check the file via the browser is quite misleading here, because it was accessible via the browser after all.